# Using sudo with multiple commands or functions

Tags: bash, sudo

Neither of these work. Can you tell me why *sudo* does not work with a function, and is there a way to make it work with a function like this?

```
yy() { yum upgrade -y; yum upgrade -y; }
sudo yy
```

or:

```
sudo $(yum upgrade -y; yum upgrade -y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a subshell. What you are doing is executing the output of the command as sudo.
Try

```
sudo bash -c 'yum upgrade -y; yum upgrade -y'
```

Comment: Perfect, so I can now run multiple commands with a single `sudo` prompt. Thanks.